# Scala code not working properly in NiFi

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-nifi

I am trying to append data to a HDFS location on a daily base, the code below works perfectly fine in spark shell ('$date' is a string for automation purpose.):

```
DF.filter(s"yy_mm_dd = '$date'").write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(s"hdfs:/path.../apend.parquet/yy_mm_dd=$date")
```

The problem I am facing now is that when I run the code in spark shell, it append all the data; But when I put the code in NiFi, it only append 0.2% of the data. Why this is happening?

In NiFi, I am using the ExecuteProcess Processor, and connected to a Output Port.

Below are the imports (might be the cause?):

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext, SaveMode}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat   
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}
```

Comment: At runtime both vanilla java and Scala are compiled as bytecode, which portable, so if it works on some env but not on other it's probably related to env diff rather than source language

Comment: It's running under the same environment, only diff is NiFi..

Comment: so that's not the same env if a dependency such as NiFi is different

Comment: Do you have the full code and architecture describing what's going on? From what I understand, the ExecuteProcess processor is calling out to a .jar file that you wrote in scala? Have you checked to make sure more than 0.2% of the data is hitting your processor, or looked for what might be different about the data that's not going through?